# Ubuntu Automatically Deleted?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning

What happened was I was programming in Ubuntu and I accidentally spilled water on my laptops keyboard. So I immediately turned it off and flipped the laptop so that the water would drain out. Then after half and hour I booted the laptop and somehow ubuntu is no more. I checked my disk partitions and the partitions are as now. I had allocated 112 GB for ubuntu and on the disk management it shows 100% available. I have dual booted Ubuntu with windows 10 and was using ubuntu when the accident happened.

Thank fully I had my work saved on SVN however, I am still confused on how did this delete a partition?

Any inputs?

I am using : Lenovo Ideapad 510 (

Comment: Half an hour is not nearly enough time for it to dry out completely with certainty. You may have fried your PC...

Comment: It was a fairly small spill however, the laptop is working fine. I am using windows with no issues. But something went wrong with the dual booted Ubuntu.

Comment: A small spill that had to *drain*?  Working fine but an operating system has disappeared?  It takes a lot of time for water and moisture to dry out of small crevices. I'd remove the battery and put it under a fan well ventilated on all sides for 24 hrs

Comment: Would use a live Ubuntu USB to get a better look at Ubuntu partition, windows will barely tell you that a partition is there.  Liquid plus a rapid power kill will mess something up.  Feel lucky that laptop still works.  I was not so lucky.

Comment: Just an update. What happened was that after the incident, the order of the Windows and Ubuntu system in the boot menu got set to default and hence it was booting into windows automatically. I fixed the boot order and am now able to get the boot menu option.